# Using FetchMany and Select in Linq to NHibernate query

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, nhibernate-futures

I have Personne (person) entity with sub collections Polices and Procedures. I want to load a batch of Personnes with those collections loaded as well, using the power of Future queries. But! I was asked not to duplicate the columns of Personne in the queries getting the Polices and Procedures, which seems wise to optimize the amount of data traveling from database to server.

Here is what I ended up doing.

```
public IList<Personne> GetForDTO(IList<int> ids)
{
    IEnumerable<Personne> query = NHibernateSession.Current.Query<Personne>()
        .Fetch(x => x.Adresse)
        .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id))
        .ToFuture();

    var queryWithPolices = NHibernateSession.Current.Query<Personne>()
        .FetchMany(x => x.Polices)
        .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id))
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x.Id,
            x.Polices
        })
        .ToFuture();

    var queryWithProcedures = NHibernateSession.Current.Query<Personne>()
        .FetchMany(x => x.Procedures)
        .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id))
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x.Id,
            x.Procedures
        })
        .ToFuture();

    return query.ToList();
}
```

This query doesn't work, with error:
Collections.IList' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object]'

It does work if I remove the Select() line call, but of course it results in the Personne columns being fetched as well as the Polices and Procedures columns.

Any idea of to fix this?

Answer (score -2):

change return type 'IList' to 'IEnumerable'

Answer (score -2):

Change your return type to `IEnumerable`:

```
public IIEnumerable<Personne> GetForDTO(IList<int> ids)
```

Comment: I tried for the sake of it but it doesn't work.

You see, the ToList() in the return statement is what fires all three queries at the same time (in one go to the database) and it returns a List<>.

The problem seems to be the internal implementation of fetch().